# KeyListener doesn't work on JFrame using BlueJ

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, keylistener

I'm doing a college work about a game. I catch the events through a KeyListener implemented by the JFrame, and it sends the events to the panel shown.
This works perfectly on both Eclipse and as an executable jar, but I've to submit it running on BlueJ. Do you know something about it? I only can hand it in BlueJ format.

I haven't posted any code because I only implement the KeyListener and throw the events through the frame, but if you need it just ask for

Comment: On the other half of the earth it's morning now :D

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.